# Route not working when parameter passed to default action

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have the following route setup.

```
$router->add('/schools', array(
    'module' => 'schools',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Schools\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 'index'
));

$router->add('/schools/:params",array(
    'module' => 'schools',
    'namespace'=>'MyNameSpace\Schools\Controllers\\',
    'controller'=>'index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'params' => 1
));
```

Problem:

```
1.  http://www.example.com/schools/23
```

Works fine

```
2.  http://www.example.com/schools/~23
```

Works as well

But,

```
3.  http://www.example.com/schools/school-name
```

does not work,
Where `school-name`, `~23` and `23` in the above URLs are parameters to the default action `(index)` of the controller.

I cannot print anything in the `initialize` method of the controller. Tried putting try catch on `main` method of  `index.php` as well, no errors.

I can't print anything when 3rd URL above is executed, I just get `1` printed on the browser, no other errors.
I then, printed matched route path in `http://www.example.com/schools/~23` and it gave

```
Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Route Object
(
    [_pattern:protected] => /schools/:params
    [_compiledPattern:protected] => #^/schools(/.*)*$#
    [_paths:protected] => Array
        (
            [module] => schools
            [namespace] => MyNameSpace\Schools\Controllers\
            [controller] => index
            [action] => index
            [params] => 1
        )

    [_methods:protected] => 
    [_hostname:protected] => 
    [_converters:protected] => 
    [_id:protected] => 34
    [_name:protected] => 
    [_beforeMatch:protected] => 
    [_group:protected] => 
)
```

Following route, the object is printed on `http://www.example.com/schools/23`

```
Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Route Object
(
    [_pattern:protected] => /schools/:action/:params
    [_compiledPattern:protected] => #^/schools/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)(/.*)*$#
    [_paths:protected] => Array
        (
            [module] => schools
            [namespace] => MyNameSpace\Schools\Controllers\
            [controller] => index
            [action] => 1
            [params] => 2
        )

    [_methods:protected] => 
    [_hostname:protected] => 
    [_converters:protected] => 
    [_id:protected] => 36
    [_name:protected] => 
    [_beforeMatch:protected] => 
    [_group:protected] => 
)
```

**UPDATE**
Surprisingly  following url also works

`http://www.example.com/schools/~school-name` but not `http://www.example.com/schools/school-name`

```
Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Route Object
(
    [_pattern:protected] => /schools/:params
    [_compiledPattern:protected] => #^/schools(/.*)*$#
    [_paths:protected] => Array
        (
            [module] => agencies
            [namespace] => MyNameSpace\Schools\Controllers\
            [controller] => index
            [action] => index
            [params] => 1
        )

    [_methods:protected] => 
    [_hostname:protected] => 
    [_converters:protected] => 
    [_id:protected] => 34
    [_name:protected] => 
    [_beforeMatch:protected] => 
    [_group:protected] => 
)
```

Can anybody help me, what I m doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If You see this `[_pattern:protected] => /schools/:action/:params`
and your code does not have this rule, then it looks like default route applied.

Create `Router` with `false` to disable default routes.

in Phalcon code it is clearly set to use default one: https://docs.phalconphp.com/3.4/en/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Router

`public function __construct(bool! defaultRoutes = true)`

Comment: I do have `/schools/:action/:params` route defined in actual code. But how come 2 example rules are working just because the parameter is numeric or has tilt sign?? And not working if alphabets (third example in my post)??

Comment: `http://www.example.com/schools/~school-name` also works but not `http://www.example.com/schools/school-name`

Comment: Rules work in reverse order. If :action defined as last and matched then it will be picked up.